# How to use the same code for onclick and oninput event

Tags: javascript

I use the following `oninput` event in:

`document.getElementById('test').onkeydown = function(event) {`

I need the same code to be executed if a certain button is clicked.
Rather that writing the code twice I wondered if it is possible to call the same code with an onclick event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the same handler for different events you could do this:

```
function handler(){
    .... your code
}

document.getElementById('test').onkeydown = handler;
document.getElementById('test').onkeyup = handler;
```

Comment: Still one question thought what if I want the onkeydown event for the enter key only?

Comment: @Ethannn  pass event object to handler and use `e.type` to search for the type of event and handle it accordingly , read here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type

Comment: `document.getElementById('test').onkeydown = function(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        handler();
    }
}` Found out already :)